# XSLT take first element that can be mapped among list of predefined mappings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML :

```xml
<sectors type="array">
   <sector>industry</sector>
   <sector>e-commerce</sector>
   <sector>logistique</sector>
<sectors>
```

I want to map those sectors with predefined list of sectors using IF logic, and keep only the first one that can be mapped.

EDIT

By 'first' I mean the first that appear in the XML document. The first XML 'sectors/sector' that can be mapped (i.e. transformed by XSLT with the help of the second list).

END-EDIT

If no one of the original sectors can be mapped, then I want "sector_other" as the new value output by XSLT.

So the output needs to be something like this :

```xml
<sectorIdentifier>
  sector_industry_materials
</sectorIdentifier>
```

Here 'sector_industry_materials' is the transformed value.

I have the following XSLT which will illustrate what I'm trying to do, but it does not work :

```xml
<sectorIdentifier>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sectors/sector"/>
</sectorIdentifier>

<!-- start:sector -->
<xsl:template match="sector">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current() = 'industry'">
            <xsl:value-of select="sector_industry_materials"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="current() = 'health'">
            <xsl:value-of select="sector_health_medical"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="sector_other"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I could use a for-each approch, but then all the mapped elements would be returned, including the "sector_other", which I want only if there is no match.

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "first one that can be mapped", is that first in the order in which they appear in the XML document, or in the order of your list (as my answer does)?

Comment: The first one that can be mapped, no matter the order of both lists. Say, if 'industry' finds a mapping value in the XSLT list, then take the corresponding target, and stop processing. If not, test 'e-commerce', and so one... If no matching is found, then put 'sector_other'.

Comment: Well, the order of ONE of the lists does matter - otherwise the word "first" is meaningless.

Comment: In that case, this is the first that appear in the XML document. The first XML 'sectors' that can be mapped (transformed by XSLT with the help of the second list). Sorry if this was confusing, I am editing the question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, you have an answer, albeit not a very elegant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant first in the order in which they appear in the XML document:

**XSLT 1.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="sectors"
  exclude-result-prefixes="s">
  <s:sector source="industry" target="sector_industry_materials" />
  <s:sector source="health" target="sector_health_medical" />
  <xsl:template match="sectors">
    <sectorIdentifier>
      <xsl:variable name="sector" select="sector[.=document('')/*/s:sector/@source][1]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sector">
          <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/s:sector[@source=$sector]/@target" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>sector_other</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </sectorIdentifier>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. But now, I have another problem, that is not related. Would you mind taking a look if you have some time ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73052447/xslt-evaluate-variable-whose-name-is-coming-from-xpath-evaluation Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/sectors">
    <sectorIdentifier>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="sector = 'industry'">sector_industry_materials</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="sector = 'health'">sector_health_medical</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>sector_other</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </sectorIdentifier>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```