# XSLT evaluate variable whose name is coming from xpath evaluation

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

Following my previous post : [XSLT take first element that can be mapped among list of predefined mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039619/xslt-take-first-element-that-can-be-mapped-among-list-of-predefined-mappings)

Is there a way to evaluate a variable, in a `xsl:value-of`, whose name is coming from the evaluation of XPATH ?

The original XML :

```xml
<sectors type="array">
   <sector>industry</sector>
   <sector>e-commerce</sector>
   <sector>logistique</sector>
<sectors>
```

This is my XSLT (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73040079/10767428) :

```xml
<xsl:import href="./sector.xslt"/>

<s:sector source="metallurgy" target="$sector_industry_materials" />
<s:sector source="accounting" target="$sector_audit_accounting" />
<s:sector source="logistics" target="$sector_service_logistics" />
<s:sector source="mass-distribution" target="$sector_distribution_mass_retail" />

<xsl:template match="sectors">
    <sectorIdentifier>
        <xsl:variable name="sector" select="sector[. = document('')/*/s:sector/@source][1]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$sector">
                <xsl:variable name="target" select="document('')/*/s:sector[@source=$sector]/@target"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$target" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sector_other"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </sectorIdentifier>
</xsl:template>
```

Here, the value of `$target` are either the strings : `$sector_industry_materials`, `$sector_audit_accounting`, `$sector_service_logistics`, `$sector_distribution_mass_retail` or `$sector_other`.

I want those strings to be evaluated against the following other XSLT, from another file, and imported in current file :

`sector.xslt` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:variable name="sector_industry_materials" >401</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="sector_audit_accounting" >374</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="sector_service_logistics" >422</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="sector_distribution_mass_retail" >387</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="sector_other" >456</xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the final output, in case the `$target` value was the string `$sector_industry_materials`, must be :

```xml
<sectorIdentifier>401</sectorIdentifier>
```

But for now, all I get is :

```xml
<sectorIdentifier>$sector_distribution_mass_retail</sectorIdentifier>
```

The thing is that with `$sector_other`, which is hard-coded, everything works fine, and I get :

```xml
<sectorIdentifier>456</sectorIdentifier>
```

SO the problem must be that name of the variables are dynamic.

Thank you

Comment: Dynamic XPath evaluation exists as an optional feature with `xsl:evaluate` only in XSLT 3.0 (Saxon 10 HE and later, Saxon 9.8 PE/EE and later, Saxon-JS 2) or as processor specific, proprietary extension in earlier versions. Which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly do you use?

Comment: This is very confusing. Could you not eliminate the middleman and map `industry` directly to `401`, `accounting` to `374` and so on? This map could be hard-coded into your stylesheet or - if you prefer - it could be stored in an external XML document. Such document does not need to be an XSLT stylesheet; in fact, making it so only complicates things.

Comment: At first sight this seems to be a very complicated way of achieving something very simple. But you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve, and it's really hard to reverse engineer the requirements from the code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree that this seems complicated, but we need to have this middleware for code generation. But I will check if there is a way to have a direct mapping between `metallurgy` and `401` in the XML file itself, instead of going through the process of finding first `sector_industry_materials`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Even with 2 maps, it should be quite simple to find the first sector that has an entry in map A using `key('sector', $mapA/key)[1]` and then lookup the corresponding value in map B using `key('mapB', $foundValue)`. At no point should there be a need to evaluate a string as an XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same technique and drill into the imported sector.xslt as an XML doc, selecting the value with XPath:

```
<xsl:when test="$sector">
  <xsl:variable name="target" select="document('')/*/s:sector[@source=$sector]/@target"/>
  <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$target" /> -->
  <xsl:value-of select="document('sector.xslt')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable[contains($target, @name)]"/>
</xsl:when>
```

It would be a little more straightforward if you changed the `s:sector/@target` values not to have `$` for variable name references, and just had the value to match the sector.xslt `xsl:variable/@name`.

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. I did not think of using the XSLT sheet as a regular XML file.